# Django function based views return form object instead of actual form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have this view of creating Post Model instance.

```
def post_create(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PostCreate()
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, 'posts/create.html', context)

    else:
        form = PostCreate(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
            blog_type = form.cleaned_data.get('blog_type')
            text = form.cleaned_data.get('text')
            status = form.cleaned_data.get('status')

            Post.objects.create(
                title=title,
                blog_type=blog_type,
                text=text,
                status=status
            )
            return redirect('post-show')
        else:
            return render(request, 'posts/create.html', context)
```

I have a form class PostCreate which is a ModelForm for my Post Model

```
class PostCreate(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title', 'blog_type', 'text', 'status'
        ]
```

And create.html have a form

```
<form action="" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

With path

```
path('posts/create', post_create, name='post-create'),
```

Server is running fine with all this. Now when I goto this path, it does not show the form. As I checked using `print(form)` in view or `{{form}}` in template gives `<posts.views.PostCreate object at 0x10b1b8a90>`. Due to this `{{form.as_p}}` is not returning anything. 
This was working fine yesterday but today, everything is fine even then not working now.

Comment: Do you have another class with the same name? (`PostCreate`)?

Comment: what is in `'post-show'`

Comment: @Selcuk omg yeah, I did. Thanks a lot. I created a Class based view PostCreate and that was causing the issue. Thank you so much.