# Django rendering Form object rather than form fields

Tags: python, django

Sure I've missed something obvious, but any help appreciated.

I have a form model:

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
```

A view:

```
def userform(req):

    context = {}
    context['user_form'] = UserForm()
    context['message'] = 'test message'

    return render(req, 'apps/userform.html', context)
```

And a template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block title %} | User Form {% endblock %} 
{% block content %}
<h1>Form page</h1>
<form method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form }}
    <button type='submit'>Send</button>
</form>
{{ message }}
{% endblock %}
```

I'm pretty sure everything is connected correctly and imported as required - the 'message' property on context renders fine under the form.

However, `{{ user_form }}` in the template renders the actual Form object instance, rather than the actual form field I'm expecting.  I see:

`<userform.views.UserForm object at 0x7fcab17e5c10>`

Then the form submit button.

What have I missed?

Django 4, if that matters.

Comment: nvm, found here in case anyone else has this issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546659/django-function-based-views-return-form-object-instead-of-actual-form/73335088#73335088) - I had the same class name elsewhere in my application

Comment: @ DanB-Web, you could add this as an answer to this question, if that worked, explain a bit, accept it, if you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was I had a class based view in the views file with the same name as my Form class - I guess that was getting instantiated, rather than the Form class. Commented out the CBV and everything worked.

If I'd looked harder at the error message, I would have probably seen this sooner as the instantiated object is clearly in the views folder, rather than the forms one...